# Queryset delete with order_by in django

Tags: django-models, django-orm

For preventing deadlock in most scenarios, it is better to have `delete` and `update` or other queries have affect on the same portion of data, work with a defined behavior. One simple practice is to use `order by` in mysql operations.
I am able to delete portion of data using order by by following query in mysql:

```
DELETE from Table where ... order by id
```

But assuming same behavior from django queryset has not the same output:

```
Table.objects.filter(...).order_by('id').delete()
```

It ignores `order_by` and simply deletes records.

Except using raw sql query, how can I use djanog orm to do the same job.

For clarifying I think two simple queries could cause a deadlock if the order of acquiring locks was arbitrary:

```
# transaction 1
select * from Table where id > 100 for update;
#transaction 2
delete from Table where id > 101 and id < 110;
```

Comment: Why do you want to sort for delete? what's inside the filter

Comment: To prevent deadlock in database, as it would lock the data by an expected pattern AFAIK.  It is currently a simple list of foreign key ids, for example (fid__in=[ids]) but I think it does not matter what is exactly the filter args, it is a general problem that makes sense for preventing deadlock.

Comment: what do you do before/after delete? I think it cause deadlock.

Comment: I have checked it using `show engine innodb status`, I always am cautious to have a minimum time range for getting a lock usually just one or two simple query. But I think it is a suggested way to have locks in order, do you mean that order of getting locks of rows has not any effect of deadlock occurring?